# Understanding CYCLE_ACTIVITY.* Haswell Performance-Monitoring Events

Tags: intel, performancecounter, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, perf

I'm trying to analyse an execution on an Intel Haswell CPU (Intel® Core™ i7-4900MQ) with the Top-down Microarchitecture Analysis Method (TMAM), described in Chapters B.1 and B.4 of the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html). (I adjust the Sandy Bridge formulas described in B.4 to the Haswell Microarchitecture if needed.)

Therefore I perform performance counter events measurements with Perf. There are some results I don’t understand:

1. `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD_P` < `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING`

This holds only for a few measurements, but still is weird. Does the PMU count halted cycles for `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING`?

2. `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING` > `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING`
   and `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` > `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING`

This applies for all measurements. When there is a L1D cache miss, the load gets transferred to the L2 cache, right? So a load missed L2 earlier also missed L1. There is the L1 instruction cache not counted here, but with `*_L2_PENDING` being 100x or even 1000x greater than `*_L1D_PENDING` it is probably not that.. Are the stalls/cycles being measured somehow separately? But than there is this formula:

`%L2_Bound = 
(CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING - CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING) / CLOCKS`

Hence `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` < `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING` is assumed (the result of the formula must be positive). (The other thing with this formula is that it should probably be `CYCLES` instead of `STALLS`. However this wouldn't solve the problem described above.) So how can this be explained?

**edit:** My OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, kernel: 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64, perf version: 3.13.11-ckt26

Comment: What is your OS and version of perf?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, version of perf: 3.13.11-ckt26

Comment: Have you checked that the version of perf you have matches your kernel?

Comment: My kernel version is 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64. The packages linux-tools-common(3.13.0-65.105, all) and linux-tools-3.13.0-65-generic(3.13.0-65.105, amd64) are installed on the system. I suppose then the perf version is the right one for my kernel? Or how do I check if my perf version is the right one?

Comment: Try to disable hyperthreading and/or prefetching and see what happens. Also measure TLB misses.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with the second part of the question, i.e., how `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING` and `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` can be larger than `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING` and `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING`, respectively.

First, note that the formula for `%L2_Bound` is from Section B.5 of the Intel Optimization Manual. The first paragraph of that section says:

> This section covers various performance tuning techniques using
>   performance monitoring events. Some techniques can be adapted in
>   general to other microarchitectures, **most of the performance events
>   are specific to Intel microarchitecture code name Sandy Bridge**.

My first hunch was that prefetching has something to do with it (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677367/understanding-haswell-performance-monitoring-events#comment89413382_33677367)). This paragraph pushed me further in the right direction; these events may represent different things in Sandy Bridge and in Haswell. Here is what they mean on [Haswell](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/haswell.html):

> CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING:    **Cycles with pending L1 data cache
>   miss loads.** CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING: **Cycles with pending L2
>   miss loads.** CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING:  **Execution stalls due to
>   L1 data cache miss loads.** CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING:     **Number of
>   loads missed L2.**

The manual also says the counters for L2 should only be used when hyperthreading is disabled. Now here is what they mean on [Sandy Bridge](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/snb.html):

> CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING:    Each cycle there was a **miss-pending
>   demand load this thread**, increment by 1.
>   CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING:     Each cycle there was a **MLC-miss
>   pending demand load this thread**, increment by 1.
>   CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING:    Each cycle there was a **miss-pending
>   demand load this thread and no uops dispatched**, increment by 1.
>   CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING:     Each cycle there was a **MLC-miss
>   pending demand load and no uops dispatched on this thread**, increment
>   by 1.

There are three important differences:

- Some of the Haswell events can only valid when HT is disabled. All SNB events are valid even when HT is enabled.
- `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` on HSW counts the number of load misses at L2, but on SNB, it counts the number of cycles during which there was at least one demand load miss at L2.
- The HSW events include all accesses, not just demand loads. In contrast, the SNB events only occur for demand loads.

On HSW, `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L2_PENDING` can be larger than `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING` because of the miss-pending loads issued by the L1D prefetcher (and/or the L2 prefetcher(s) depending on whether the prefetcher increments the counter for the same level of cache). Similarly, while they count different things, `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` can be larger than `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING` due to prefetching. TLB prefetching and prefetching at other MMU caches may also impact these performance events on HSW. On the other hand, on SNB, it is guaranteed that `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L2_PENDING` < `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.STALLS_L1D_PENDING`, and that's why the `%L2_Bound` formula is valid on SNB.

Like I said in the comment, disabling HT and/or [prefetching](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors) may "fix" your problem.

Actually, the Intel spec update document for the Mobile Haswell processors mentions two bugs that affect `CYCLES_L2_PENDING`:

- HSM63: The intended behavior of `CYCLES_L2_PENDING` on Haswell is to count only for demand loads, but it may count inaccurately in SMT mode.
- HSM80: `CYCLES_L2_PENDING` may overcount due to requests from the next page prefetcher.

I think you can minimize the error in `CYCLES_L2_PENDING` by disabling SMT (either in BIOS or putting the other logical core into sleep). In addition, try to not trigger the NPP. This can be achieved by avoiding locations towards the end of a virtual page where the translation of the next page is not already in the TLB hierarchy.

Related: [When L1 misses are a lot different than L2 accesses… TLB related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475118/when-l1-misses-are-a-lot-different-than-l2-accesses-tlb-related)

Regarding the first part of the question, i.e., how `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD_P` can be smaller than `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING`. One explanation that I could think of is that the `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING` occurs for loads issued from (some) other threads (in particular, on the same physical core), not just the halted thread. Erratum HSM146 mentions that `CYCLES_LDM_PENDING` may count inaccurately when the logical core is not in C0, which explains how `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD_P` can be smaller than `CYCLES_LDM_PENDING`. Disabling HT may eliminate this inaccuracy, although the spec update document doesn't provide any workaround.

Comment: On Skylake the counter `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_PENDING` is renamed to `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_MISS` (perf list shows it that way). Also on Haswell `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING` stated for `event=0xA3,umask=0x2,cmask=0x2`. On Skylake the same event,umask,cmask defines `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L3_MISS` and there is no `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_LDM_PENDING` anymore, but `CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_MEM_ANY` was added as `event=0xA3,umask=0x10,cmask=0x10`.

Comment: What is LDM un LDM_PENDING anyway?

Comment: @BeeOnRope It stands for Load Dependency Matrix.